# call extjs getById method with variable

Tags: extjs

I have a strange problem in my code. I want to get an item from store by its id. the value of itemId is 1 and I get null for firstItem.

```
    var itemId = dragIdSplit[1];
    var firstItem = me.getPStore().getById(itemId);
```

Then if I just call getById(1) the correct value will be returned. Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below changes. you doing split so it's a string you have to convert it into integer.

```
var itemId = parseInt( dragIdSplit[1]);
    var firstItem = me.getPStore().getById(itemId);
```